# How to get list of directories except some directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to get list of directories and exclude some directories by name.

I *Linux* I may do something like this:

`ls -d */ | egrep -v '^common/$|^static/$|^static_src/$|^templates/$`

How to do it in *Windows* *cmd*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dir /ad /b | findstr /v /x /c:"common" /c:"static" /c:"static_src" /c:"templates"
```

Or, if the folder names don't contain spaces,

```
dir /ad /b | findstr /v /x "common static static_src templates"
```